# Intellij importing existing intellij projects

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I import an existing Intellij project into Intellij I cannot run the unit tests. I right-click on the test but the Run choice is missing in the context menu. Why does this happen?  What is the fix?

This is using Intellij 2017.2.5  The project is Java 8/Gradle 4.12

thanks

Comment: Are you able to run your tests with gradle? Is your directory with tests marked as "test source" in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, I can run my tests via command-line.  The second question: That is part of the problem. For some reason none of the project's directories are marked correctly when I import the existing project. Why does Intellij "forget" how the project is configured? Shouldn't all this be stored somewhere in the .idea directory that is within the project directory?

Comment: Are you able to start the tests after marking proper folders in IntelliJ manually as "source" and "test source"?

Comment: No, assigning the folders does not fix the run problem.

Comment: Attach a screenshot, showing complete IDE window with the context menu. Can you run tests by manually [creating JUnit Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) Also make sure you have **JUnit** bundled plugin enabled.

Comment: I asked my Dev lead. He knew the problem. When importing a project always point to the build.gradle when importing. That has worked perfectly every single time since. thanks.